# Split latitude/longitude by degree to make file names and folder directory names

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

This code works and does exactly as I want, but I am wondering if/how it could be done faster/more efficiently? This runs quickly on a demo file, but bogs down when I introduce much larger files (3-100GB).

**Premise:**

Take a large list of latitudes and longitudes remove the negative values (WGS1984) and put them into a North, South, East, West space. Eliminate decimal places.

Use a shortened version of latitude and longitudes for directory creation.

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import h5py

hdf_file = '/path/to/file/lat_lon.h5'
ndir_root = '/output/path/where/directories/are/created/'
# split the file into two chunks to avoid memory error.
chunks = [0, 50, 100]
# open chunked file
for half in range(len(chunks) - 1):
    hf = h5py.File(hdf_file, 'r')
    print 'file loaded. reading meta lat/lon.'

    meta_latitude = hf['latitude'][chunks[half]:chunks[half + 1]]
    meta_longitude = hf['longitude'][chunks[half]:chunks[half + 1]]

    meta_df = pd.DataFrame({'longitude': meta_longitude, 'latitude': meta_latitude})
    print meta_df

    # create an empty list to store coordinates
    lat_list = []
    lon_list = []
    for lat in meta_df['latitude']:
        lat_list.append(lat)
    for lon in meta_df['longitude']:
        lon_list.append(lon)

    # take coordinates from list and convert to a numpy array
    latitude_list = np.asarray(lat_list, dtype=float)
    longitude_list = np.asarray(lon_list, dtype=float)

    # convert numpy array to a string
    lat_list_str = latitude_list.astype(str)

    # make copies to avoid contamination in for loop processing
    lat_list_str_copy_1 = lat_list_str
    lat_list_str_copy_2 = lat_list_str

    # remove negative values, add North, South, East West.
    letter = set('-')

    for lat_check in lat_list_str_copy_1:
        if letter & set(lat_check):
            lat_list_str3 = [i.replace('-', 'S') for i in lat_list_str_copy_1]
        else:
            lat_list_str3 = ['N' + lat_addchar for lat_addchar in lat_list_str_copy_1]

    # remove the decimal for directory creation
    lat = [i.replace('.', '') for i in lat_list_str3]

    lon_list_str = longitude_list.astype(str)

    # make copies to avoid contamination in for loop processing
    lon_list_str_copy_1 = lon_list_str
    lon_list_str_copy_2 = lon_list_str

    for lon_check in lon_list_str_copy_1:
        if letter & set(lon_check):
            lon_list_str3 = [i.replace('-', 'W') for i in lon_list_str_copy_1]
        else:
            lon_list_str3 = ['E' + lon_addchar for lon_addchar in lon_list_str_copy_1]

    lon = [i.replace('.', '') for i in lon_list_str3]

    for i in lat:
        if len(i) < 4:
            i = i + '0'

    for i in lon:
        if len(i) < 5:
            i = '0' + i

    meta_df['y'] = lat
    meta_df['x'] = lon
    meta_df['lon_list_str'] = lon_list_str
    meta_df['lat_list_str'] = lat_list_str

    # convert to int and take only values to left of decimal as folder name
    short_lon_int = [i.split('.')[0] for i in lon_list_str_copy_2]
    short_lat_int = [i.split('.')[0] for i in lat_list_str_copy_2]

    short_lon = map(int, short_lon_int)
    short_lat = map(int, short_lat_int)

    for i in short_lat:
        if i % 3 > 0:
            i -= 1
    for i in short_lon:
        if i % 3 > 0:
            i -= 1

    short_lat_str = map(str, short_lat)
    short_lon_str = map(str, short_lon)

    for lat_check in short_lat_str:
        if letter & set(lat_check):
            short_lat_int_final = [i.replace('-', 'S') for i in short_lat_str]
        else:
            short_lat_int_final = ['N' + lat_addchar for lat_addchar in short_lat_str]

    for lon_check in short_lon_str:
        if letter & set(lon_check):
            short_lon_int_final = [i.replace('-', 'W') for i in short_lon_str]
        else:
            short_lon_int_final = ['E' + lon_addchar for lon_addchar in short_lon_str]

    for a, b in zip(short_lon_int_final, short_lat_int_final):
        ndir = a + b
        print ndir
        if not os.path.exists(ndir_root + ndir):
            os.mkdir(ndir_root + ndir)
```

Please let me know if anything needs clarification. This is a smaller chunk out of a larger script so some variables appear undefined.

**Edit:**
Per comment requests a sample file has been linked.
[link to hdf file with lat/lon data.](https://github.com/kaizergilroy/lat_lon_parsing/blob/master/lat_lon.h5)

Comment: Could you please include the code which leads to the creation of the `meta_df` object, as well as an example input file, so that we can try out your program without errors?

Comment: Are you sure this code is doing what you expect? While reading it, I am beginning to have some doubts.

Comment: Yep will post shortly once laptop is back on wifi. Are we allowed to upload files?... Demo file with lat/lon is small (4kb).

Comment: You probably should upload the data file somewhere else and provide a link in the question.

Comment: Yeah i got the feeling too, that your code isn't doing what you expect . For example :for lat_check in lat_list_str_copy_1 you are looping through the copy and there isn't any need to do that since you are only using the final item of the array, because you redefine each time your new array lat_list_str3. Same with your other fors.

Comment: Apologies for delay, the beginning of code has been added and a sample file is linked on github.

Comment: Updated my answer. Take a look please.

Comment: It's still not clear to me what the purpose of the code is. Is it only supposed to create empty directories, or is there something else supposed to happen?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes this is only part of a script that creates the directories. Later on, csv files are written to these directories using more precision from the lat/lons to keep them unique, but still be able to be binned by a degreen of lat/lon. The full lat/lon file ends up having ~650 csvs per directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Bug and accidental quadratic runtime

> ```
> for lat_check in lat_list_str_copy_1:
>     if letter & set(lat_check):
>         lat_list_str3 = [i.replace('-', 'S') for i in lat_list_str_copy_1]
>     else:
>         lat_list_str3 = ['N' + lat_addchar for lat_addchar in lat_list_str_copy_1]
> ```

This code (which occurs with variations four times in your program) is probably the cause for the program becoming extremely slow for large input files:

Inside the `for` loop you want to format only the current latitude value, but instead the whole list is rewritten each time. If you have a list with *n* = 1000 items, the inner code (`i.replace('-', 'S')` or `'N' + lat_addchar`) is executed *n*<sup>2</sup> = 1 000 000 times, of which the first 999 000 times were wasted effort.

In addition, the result is wrong, because you either replace `'-'` by `'S'` in *all* items, or prepend `'N'` to *all* items, depending of the value of only the last item in the list.

**Side note**

> ```
> letter = set('-')
> if letter & set(lat_check):
>     …
> ```

This is actually a clever idea, if you wanted to check if any of *several* letters is contained in a string. However, for a single letter, you can simply write the following:

```
if '-' in lat_check:
    …
```

(But checking for negative values can be done more easily, see below.)

#### Unused results

> ```
> for i in lat:
>     if len(i) < 4:
>         i = i + '0'
>
> for i in lon:
>     if len(i) < 5:
>         i = '0' + i
> ```

> ```
> for i in short_lat:
>     if i % 3 > 0:
>         i -= 1
> for i in short_lon:
>     if i % 3 > 0:
>         i -= 1
> ```

These have no effect and can simply be removed, because the resulting value of `i` is not used anywhere and is overwritten in the next loop iteration anyway.

> ```
> meta_df['y'] = lat
> meta_df['x'] = lon
> meta_df['lon_list_str'] = lon_list_str
> meta_df['lat_list_str'] = lat_list_str
> ```

This can be removed as well, because `meta_df` isn't used anywhere later on.

Since now the lists `lat` and `lon` aren't used anymore, all the computations leading to their creation can be removed, too. This involves the intermediate lists `lat_list_str3` and `lon_list_str3`, as well as `lat_list_str_copy_1` and `lon_list_str_copy_1`.

#### Assignments don't make copies

> ```
> # make copies to avoid contamination in for loop processing
> lat_list_str_copy_1 = lat_list_str
> lat_list_str_copy_2 = lat_list_str
> […]
> lon_list_str_copy_1 = lon_list_str
> lon_list_str_copy_2 = lon_list_str
> ```

Besides `lat_list_str_copy_1` and `lon_list_str_copy_1` now not being used anymore, this doesn't do what you think:

These assignments only attach **new names** to the **existing** list objects, the do not create new copies of the lists!

However, making copies wouldn't have been necessary at all, because they were never modified.

You can just use the original name of the list wherever the `*_copy_1` or `*_copy_2` names are used.

This does create a new list, as you intended:

> ```
> lat_list = []
> for lat in meta_df['latitude']:
>     lat_list.append(lat)
> ```

However, it could more simply be written as

```
lat_list = list(meta_df['latitude'])
```

(But it turns out that creating this list wasn't necessary either, see below.)

If you are astonished by how assignments don't make copies in Python, you can read a good explanation in this [blog post](http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list).

#### Simplified approach

After these first steps of cleaning up, the way the coordinates take through your program becomes more apparent:

`h5py.File` →
`pd.DataFrame` →
list of numbers →
NumPy `float` array →
NumPy `str` array →
list of strings (*actual processing:* remove parts after decimal point) →
list of integers →
list of strings →
list of strings (*actual processing:* remove minus sign, add N/S/E/W prefix).

This chain is replicated for latitudes and for longitudes.

I hope you can agree with me that the number of intermediate steps seems excessive compared to the actual work done.

I suggest the following approach:

- Treat (longitude, latitude) pairs as single objects.
- Iterate directly over the contents of the `h5py.File` object, processing one coordinate at a time (using a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)), instead of storing many coordinates at once in lists or other containers. If `h5py` is implemented properly, this should lead to low memory consumption regardless of the input file size and make manual management of chunk processing unnecessary.
- Perform only a single conversion, namely when formatting the numeric value of a coordinate as the string that is used as the name of a new directory.
- Organize each task of which the program is composed into its own function. This has the following benefits:

  - It is easier for future readers of the code to understand what the program does.
  - It is easier to test whether the individual task is implemented correctly.
  - It forces you to think more thoroughly about your program, leading to simpler code.
  - New functionality can be added by adding more functions and reusing existing functions, instead of duplicating and modifying the same code, which is tedious and error-prone.

Here is how would write the program:

```
from itertools import izip
import errno
import h5py
import os


def generate_coordinates(input_filename):
    """Generate all (longitude, latitude) pairs contained in the input file."""
    with h5py.File(input_filename, 'r') as hf:
        for coordinate in izip(hf['longitude'], hf['latitude']):
            yield coordinate


def format_coordinate(coordinate):
    """Format a pair of angles (longitude, latitude) as an 8-character string:

    >>> format_coordinate((0.5, 12.3))
    'E000N012'
    >>> format_coordinate((-40.23, -138.652))
    'W040S138'
    """
    def format_parts():
        fmt = '{prefix}{value:03d}'
        for angle, directions in zip(coordinate, ['EW', 'NS']):
            if angle >= 0:
                yield fmt.format(prefix=directions[0], value=int(angle))
            else:
                yield fmt.format(prefix=directions[1], value=int(-angle))
    return ''.join(format_parts())


def make_sure_path_exists(path, verbose=True):
    """Create the directory at the specified path if it doesn't exist.

    If verbose, print the name of the created directory.
    """
    try:
        os.makedirs(path)
    except OSError as exception:
        if exception.errno != errno.EEXIST:
            raise
    else:
        if verbose:
            print 'created directory {}'.format(path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for c in generate_coordinates('/path/to/input_file'):
        dir_name = format_coordinate(c)
        make_sure_path_exists(os.path.join('/output/dir', dir_name))
```

#### Remarks

- The *docstrings* at the beginning of the functions are used by the help system of Python, e.g. when using the `help` function in an interactive Python session, or when running the `pydoc` command from the command line. In addition, they can contain [*doctests*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html), which not only provide examples for how to use a function, but can also be automatically executed in order to test the function.
- Using the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) syntax ensures that the input file is closed when the program is finished (`h5py.File` supports it).
- Using `izip` in `generate_coordinates` prevents loading the entire file contents at once. If you are using Python 3, the regular `zip` function already behaves like this.
- Inside the `format_coordinate` function there is a local function `format_parts` generating the two parts of the result for the latitude and the longitude, which are then joined together. It uses the [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function to format each angle of the coordinate as a prefix and a three-digit zero-filled number.
- I have taken the `make_sure_path_exists` function from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273192/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-and-create-it-if-necessary/5032238#5032238) on StackOverflow and modified it slightly.
- The [`if __name__ == '__main__'` idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) prevents the program to be executed when the file is not run as a script, but imported as a module.
- `os.path.join` is the preferred way to combine paths, as opposed to manual string concatenation, because it is platform-independent and removes the possibility of errors such as combining `A` and `B` to `AB` instead of `A/B`.

Comment: Masterclass, I ran the file _without_ your recommended workflow for folder creation and did end up running into a bug not seen during small tests. I incorporated your recommended function and it ran seamlessly. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT : I highly suggest you check out mkrieger1's answer**

**One loop for the whole process:**

So the reason the whole process takes so long to complete is because you are looping for every operation over all your list again and again when you can simply do it in one go.

```
letter = set('-')

lat_result = []
lon_result = []
short_lon_result = []
short_lat_result = []
```

Since we are talking about latitude/longitude pairs we can use that to our advantage and access both lists in one go because we have the same count of items for both lists.

```
for count in range(len(lat_list_str)):
    # Latitude operation

    lat_check = lat_list_str[count]

    short_lat=int(float(lat_check))
    if short_lat % 3 > 0:
        short_lat -= 1
    short_lat = str(short_lat)
```

Short latitude has the same sign as lat_check.

```
    if letter & set(lat_check):
        temp_lat_check = lat_check.replace('-', 'S')
        short_lat = short_lat.replace('-', 'S')
    else:
        temp_lat_check = 'N' + lat_check
        short_lat = 'N' + short_lat

    lat = temp_lat_check.replace('.', '')

    if len(lat) < 5:
        lat = '0'+lat

    lat_result.append(lat)
    short_lat_result.append(short_lat)

    # Longitude operation
    lon_check = lon_list_str[count]

    short_lon=int(float(lon_check))
    if short_lon % 3 > 0:
        short_lon -= 1

    short_lon=str(short_lon)
```

Same goes for longitude, it has the same sign as lon_check.

```
    if letter & set(lon_check):
        temp_lon_check = lon_check.replace('-', 'W')
        short_lon = short_lon.replace('-', 'W')
    else:
        temp_lon_check  = 'E' + lon_check
        short_lon = 'E' + short_lon


    lon = temp_lon_check.replace('.', '')
    if len(lon) < 5:
        lon = '0'+lon

    lon_result.append(lon)
    short_lon_result.append(short_lon)


meta_df['y'] = lat_result
meta_df['x'] = lon_result
```

To be honest I don't understand why you would store to your dataframe
lon_list_str and lat_list_str again when they have the exact same values as
your longitude and latitude keys. The following part seems unneeded to me:

```
meta_df['lon_list_str'] = lon_list_str
meta_df['lat_list_str'] = lat_list_str
```

Comment: Yep one `for` loop makes a lot more sense, thanks! I did end up taking out  `if short_lon % 3 > 0: short_lon -= 1` because it kept changing the coords from 179 to 180, but other than that it worked really well!